# Cgo: Write memory in C allocated by Go

Tags: c, go, cgo, unsafe-pointers

For a non-struct slice in Go

```
a := []byte{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

And pass to C via `unsafe.Pointer()`

```
C.some_method((*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&a[0])), C.int(len(a)))
```

Is it safe to write anything into this pointer with caution on it's length?

```
void some_method(char* a, int a_len) {
    for (int i=0; i<a_len; i++) {
        a[i] = i+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo#hdr-Passing_pointers, yes you can write to values within the rules laid out in the docs.

Comment: @JimB I can only found things like you can "pass" pointer bewteen Go and C with certain criteria but seems nothing explicitly saying it's ok to write in peers' heap.  Should I simply consider anything allowed to pass between are also writable? (if not accounting thread safe)

Comment: There are some corner cases where https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#KeepAlive might help prevent items from being recycled before you are ready for that to happen. I would have thought that would be mentioned in the cgo doc but it isn't.

Comment: @Tinkerer Oh! Yes. You reminded me I also need to consider GC might move the pointer address! Need to consider this too!

Comment: @WilsonLuniz that's *exactly* what the pointer-passing rules are about. You can safely use the pointer without worrying about the GC moving it for the duration of the C function call, but it's illegal to *retain* it past the function's return (if you need something like that, retain a `cgo.Handle` instead).

Answer (score 0):

After a little research and reading comments, I think here're a few things to caution:

- For async/multi-thread in C, you need to make sure GC won't collect you pointer. This can be done via `runtime.KeepAlive()`
- GC may move you memory allocation. `unsafe.Pointer` won't get update if it do so(https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe#Pointer). But there's a pin mechanism coming soon(https://github.com/golang/go/issues/46787).
- `//go:uintptrescapes` unlikely to work for CGO, use with caution.

Comment: That bug also mentioned `//go:uintptrescapes` which likely deserves a mention of its own here.

Comment: Worth to mention but it I reckon if it's a bug. Is there any issue/discussion I can read from?

Comment: This is frequently used when doing syscalls from go where the raw syscall API is expecting a ptr as one of the arguments. Converting a memory address to a `uintptr` breaks the ptr keep alive. By prefixing the go function with this pragma comment the compiler delays GC on converted ptrs until after the call completes. This is a more implicit `runtime.KeepAlive` trick.